# WCF + load balancing + HTTPS to HTTP, authenticationMode="IssuedTokenOverTransport"

Tags: c#, wcf, binding

I am struggling from last one week, land up in some issue related to WCF. 
We have implemented load balancing which takes https request from client and unpacks the message and send request as plain HTTP to the web server. As client side needs to talk to load balancer, we have implemented custom binding which uses transport as the mechanism. So can connect to load balancer but on server side it uses http protocol. we are using token based as the security mode.

Also is it possble to have both client / server different binidngs. As client I need to have https and server just we need to have http., I have followed few artciles and try different options.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637921/cannot-find-a-token-authenticator-for-the-system-identitymodel-tokens-usernames) 
[enter link description here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ukadc/2010/04/22/setting-up-wcf-with-a-load-balancer-using-ssl-in-the-middle/)

Also I will like to mention that on the load balancer, we have installed root DNS certificate and actual certificate is installed on the web server.

Details of client config file.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.serviceModel>

        <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="custom">
          <clientCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

      <bindings>

        <customBinding>
        <binding name="Federated">
          <security authenticationMode="IssuedTokenOverTransport" enableUnsecuredResponse="true" >
            <issuedTokenParameters keyType="SymmetricKey" tokenType="http://*********#SAMLV1.1">
              <issuer address="https://localhost:84/Token.svc" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="STSBinding">
            <identity>
              <dns value="*****.com"/>
            </identity>
              </issuer>

              <issuerMetadata address="https://localhost:84/Token.svc/mex">
            <identity>
              <dns value="*****.com"/>
            </identity>
              </issuerMetadata>
            </issuedTokenParameters>
          </security>
          <textMessageEncoding>
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"/>
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="Internal">
          <security authenticationMode="IssuedTokenOverTransport"  enableUnsecuredResponse="true" >
            <issuedTokenParameters keyType="SymmetricKey" tokenType="http://*********#SAMLV1.1">
              <issuer address="https://localhost:84/Token.svc" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="STSInternal">
            <identity>
              <dns value="*****.com"/>
            </identity>
              </issuer>

              <issuerMetadata address="https://localhost:84/Token.svc/mex">
            <identity>
              <dns value="*****.com"/>
            </identity>
              </issuerMetadata>
            </issuedTokenParameters>
          </security>
          <textMessageEncoding>
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"/>
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="STSInternal">
          <security authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport" allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true" enableUnsecuredResponse="true" />
          <textMessageEncoding>
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"/>
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
             <binding name="FederatedMessage">
          <security authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport" allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true" enableUnsecuredResponse="true" />
          <textMessageEncoding>
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"/>
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
        </binding>

          </customBinding>


          <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basic">
          <reliableSession enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="server">
          <reliableSession enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <message negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
          </wsHttpBinding>
          <ws2007HttpBinding>
        <binding name="STSBinding">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="STSAnonymous">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="STSInternal">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
          </ws2007HttpBinding>   
            <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Federated" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message issuedKeyType="SymmetricKey" issuedTokenType="http://*********#SAMLV1.1" negotiateServiceCredential="true">
              <issuer address="https://localhost:84/Token.svc" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="STSBinding" />

              <issuerMetadata address="https://localhost:84/Token.svc/mex" />
            </message>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="Internal" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message issuedKeyType="SymmetricKey" issuedTokenType="http://*********#SAMLV1.1">
              <issuer address="https://localhost:84/Token.svc" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="STSInternal">
            <identity>
              <dns value="*****.com" />
            </identity>
              </issuer>

              <issuerMetadata address="https://localhost:84/Token.svc/mex">
            <identity>
              <dns value="*****.com" />
            </identity>
              </issuerMetadata>
            </message>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="FederatedMessage" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message issuedKeyType="SymmetricKey" issuedTokenType="http://*********#SAMLV1.1" negotiateServiceCredential="true">
              <issuer address="https://localhost:84/Token.svc" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="STSBinding" />

              <issuerMetadata address="https://localhost:84/Token.svc/mex" />
            </message>
          </security>
        </binding>
          </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>    
        </bindings>
        <client>
        <!-- 2 end points -->
          <endpoint address="https://localhost:84/Token.svc/Token" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="Federated" contract="Users.IUserService" name="CustomBinding_IUserService" behaviorConfiguration="custom">
        <identity>
          <dns value="*****.com" />
        </identity>
          </endpoint>     
           <endpoint address="https://localhost:84/Ser.svc/User" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="Federated" contract="Users.IUserService" name="CustomBinding_IUserService" behaviorConfiguration="custom">
        <identity>
          <dns value="*****.com" />
        </identity>
          </endpoint>  
        </client>
      </system.serviceModel>


    </configuration>
```

Details of server Config

```
          <system.serviceModel>
        <extensions>
          <bindingExtensions>
        <add name="integrationBinding" type="*******" />
          </bindingExtensions>
        </extensions>
        <diagnostics>
          <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
        </diagnostics>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Name1">
          <!--To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment-->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <!--To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information-->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="*****" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="400" maxConcurrentInstances="400" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="Name2">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" revocationMode="Online" />
              <certificate findValue="*****" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
            </clientCertificate>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="*****" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="******" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>

        <behavior name="Name3">
          <clientCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <defaultCertificate findValue="*****" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
            </serviceCertificate>
            <clientCertificate findValue="*****" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
          <integrationBinding>
        <binding name="TokenIntegrated" securityMode="Message" />
          </integrationBinding>

          <netMsmqBinding>
        <binding name="MsmqBinding" exactlyOnce="false" durable="true" queueTransferProtocol="Srmp">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
          </netMsmqBinding>

          <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basic">
          <reliableSession enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="server">
          <reliableSession enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <message negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
          </wsHttpBinding>
          <ws2007HttpBinding>
        <binding name="TokenBinding">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="STSAnonymous">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="TokenInternal">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
          </ws2007HttpBinding>   
    <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Federated" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <message issuedKeyType="SymmetricKey" issuedTokenType="http://******#SAMLV1.1" negotiateServiceCredential="true">
              <issuer address="http://localhost:84/Token.svc" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TokenBinding" />
              <!-- Metadata address for Security Token Service -->
              <issuerMetadata address="http://localhost:84/Token.svc/mex" />
            </message>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="Internal" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <message issuedKeyType="SymmetricKey" issuedTokenType="http://******#SAMLV1.1">
              <issuer address="http://localhost:84/Token.svc" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TokenInternal">
            <identity>
              <dns value="****com" />
            </identity>
              </issuer>
              <!-- Metadata address for Security Token Service -->``
              <issuerMetadata address="http://localhost:84/Token.svc/mex">
            <identity>
              <dns value="****com" />
            </identity>
              </issuerMetadata>
            </message>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="FederatedMessage" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <message issuedKeyType="SymmetricKey" issuedTokenType="http:// ******#SAMLV1.1" negotiateServiceCredential="true">
              <issuer address="http://localhost:84/Token.svc" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TokenBinding" />
              <!-- Metadata address for Security Token Service -->
              <issuerMetadata address="http://localhost:84/Token.svc/mex" />
            </message>
          </security>
        </binding>
          </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>      
        </bindings>
        <services>
          <service name="Name4" behaviorConfiguration="Name2">
        <endpoint address="" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TokenBinding" contract="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrust13SyncContract" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="Internal" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TokenInternal" contract="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrust13SyncContract" />
        <endpoint address="Federated" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Federated" contract="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrust13SyncContract" />
        <endpoint address="Anonymous" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="STSAnonymous" contract="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrust13SyncContract" />
        <endpoint address="Integrated" binding="integrationBinding" bindingConfiguration="TokenIntegrated" contract="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrust13SyncContract" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:84/Token.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
          </service>
          <service name="Name5" behaviorConfiguration="Name1">


        <endpoint address="User" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Federated" bindingNamespace="****/bindings" contract="****.IUserService" />


        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:84/Service.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
          </service>
        </services>


      </system.serviceModel>
```

Getting following error message Cannot find a token authenticator for the 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.UserNameSecurityToken' token type. Tokens of that type cannot be accepted according to current security settings.

Comment: Getting following error message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find a token authenticator for the 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.UserNameSecurityToken' token type.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637921/cannot-find-a-token-authenticator-for-the-system-identitymodel-tokens-usernames)

Comment: Thanks, the service works fine if I remove load balancing and just call the web server directly with client and server both having same binding configuration,