# How to Accept BinarySecurityToken in WCF?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf-security

I'm creating a client that is consuming a web service provided to me by a customer. Now, I know for a fact the request goes through properly because Fiddler shows me the expected response. However, when this response reaches Visual Studio, it is unable to get parsed. I get the following error.

`Cannot find a token authenticator for the 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken' token type. Tokens of that type cannot be accepted according to current security settings.`

These are the details:

- Web service authenticates client by username and password applied to ClientCredentials
  `var service = new ThatService.Config1Client();
          service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = SSO_USERNAME;
          service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = SSO_PASSWORD;`
- Binding for service is:
  `<basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="Config1Binding" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>`
- The web service response, which is successful, is this:
  `<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
       <wsse:BinarySecurityToken wsu:Id="bst9162663ec77b11e68fe1000002849f3e" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
       <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="ts91626640c77b11e6aaf4000002849f3e" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
          <wsu:Created>2016-12-21T12:47:01Z</wsu:Created>
          <wsu:Expires>2016-12-21T12:47:31Z</wsu:Expires>
       </wsu:Timestamp>
       <dsig:Signature xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <dsig:SignedInfo>
             <dsig:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
             <dsig:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
             <dsig:Reference URI="#ts91626640c77b11e6aaf4000002849f3e">
                <dsig:Transforms>
                   <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </dsig:Transforms>
                <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <dsig:DigestValue>8Nzthh4Iq5CQ84Vkqf3m8JUW6dY=</dsig:DigestValue>
             </dsig:Reference>
             <dsig:Reference URI="#DSIG-9162663fc77b11e69538000002849f3e">
                <dsig:Transforms>
                   <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </dsig:Transforms>
                <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <dsig:DigestValue>schVLt5XWejFzwLVExDAS09WiVE=</dsig:DigestValue>
             </dsig:Reference>
          </dsig:SignedInfo>
          <dsig:SignatureValue>tM0rKAA7c72BDMjt9H/4qLS4pqnFnQeyBzUYK0SPOAkMKumFTHSszPlRDkPOAh7sTMyzPgBWVxrKJd6IVbSNDpHAD9OZ/v5ZbqCG/xJLWQdUtgH9TqJ1EKCjBAOFsicnXylHxyGZqzpR506lmbTu0k8CL7e+DAv7cHXgRyGIMPo=</dsig:SignatureValue>
          <dsig:KeyInfo>
             <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                <wsse:Reference URI="#bst9162663ec77b11e68fe1000002849f3e" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
             </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
          </dsig:KeyInfo>
       </dsig:Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body wsu:Id="DSIG-9162663fc77b11e69538000002849f3e" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:wst-05-02="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust" xmlns:wsc="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:sapsp="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/security/SecurityPolicy" xmlns:wssp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:wssc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">
    <ns2:GetLoginSessionCustomerResponse xmlns:ns2="http://confidential.url/example">
       <return>CUSTOMERSPECIFICDETAILS</return>
    </ns2:GetLoginSessionCustomerResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
  </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`

Comment: can you share code?

Comment: You can find solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38459294/2871356), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12641950/2871356) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21987510/2871356)

Comment: @Aqdas, code is already shared. Which code are you talking about? The responses you mentioned are different from my need. I am submitting username and password and receiving a certificate.

Answer (score 0):

i guess the problem is here

```
<transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
```

You are specifying ClientCredentialType to None which Specifies that the client does not need to present any credential. This translates to an anonymous client.

I guess it would be great if you go through this one [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789011(v=vs.110).aspx) posted at msdn.
It would be also great if you have a look at [selecting a credential type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733836(v=vs.110).aspx)